# String replace regex

Tags: java, regex

So I'm struggling with this one a little bit.  When I'm pulling strings from somewhere It's decided to add spaces in between every character.

I just need a quick regex to:

- Replace single spaces with no space
- replace triple spaces with 1 space (since `" "` turns into `"   "` with the added spaces).

Can someone help with this regex?   I know how to do this for a single / multiple spaces, but not turning x number of spaces into 1 space.

Comment: what is `add spaces in between every character`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s{3}", " ");  // Replace 3 spaces with one.
```

I assume you know to figure out, replacing single space with no space.

- `{n}` matches exactly `n` spaces.
- `{0,n}` matches 0 to n spaces.
- `{4,}` matches 4 or more spaces.

To replace both `single space` with no space and `3 spaces` with 1 space, you can use the below regex: -

```
s = "He llo   World";
s = s.replaceAll("(\\S)\\s{1}(\\S)", "$1$2").replaceAll("\\s{3}", " ");

System.out.println(s);
```

**Ouput**: -

```
Hello World
```

**Order matters here**. Because, `3 spaces` will be converted to `single space` with the 2nd regex. If we use it before the 1st one, then eventually it will be replaced by `no-space`.

**`(\\S)\\s{1}(\\S)`** -> `\\S` is to ensure that only single space is replaced. `\\S` represents non-space character. If you don't have it, it will replace all the space character with no-space.

Comment: @F.J Couldn't understand what are you saying?  `(\\S)\\s{1}(\\S)` will first replace all the single space character. Then `\\s{3}` will replace the 3 space character with a space. Is there any problem in this?

Comment: @F.J Ok, may be you added that comment before me updating the post. :)

Comment: Yeah my comment was from when you first posted, deleted it since it is no longer applicable.

Comment: @F.J You shouldn't delete comments just because they're outdated. Everyone can see from the timestamp and the edit revisions of the posts what came before what. Only delete inappropriate or wrong comments (that were not answered or referred to by someone).

Answer (score 4):

It is a little tricky, but here is a single regex solution:

```
// becomes "test string"
"t e s t   s t r i n g".replaceAll("( )  | ", "$1");
```

Example: http://ideone.com/O6DSk

This works because if a triple space is matched, one of the spaces will be saved in capture group 1, but if a single space is matched capture group 1 is empty.  When we replace the match by the contents of the group it will turn three spaces into one and remove single spaces.

Comment: **Very** nice. I like this solution.

Comment: +1 Liked this solution so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Replace single spaces with no space replace triple spaces with 1 space.

<strike>That's no job for regular expressions.</strike>

It *is* a job for regex after all.

```
input.replaceAll("(?<=\S) (?=\S)", "").replaceAll(" {3,}", " ");
```

The first regex replaces all single spaces that are preceded by a non-space (look-behind, `(?<=\S)`) and are followed by a non-space (look-ahead `(?=\S)`).

The other regex takes care of remaining triple spaces (or even more).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use `replaceAll()` with your desired combination with some workaround as below:

```
//locate 3 spaces and mark them using some special chars
myString = myString.replaceAll("   ", "@@@"); //use some special combination

//replace single spaces with no spaces
myString = myString.replaceAll(" ", "");

//now replace marked 3 spaces with one space
myString = myString.replaceAll("@@@", " "); //use the same special combination
```

Comment: The last one should be replaced with `" "` and not `""`.

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo. I corrected.

Comment: Thought so. What if the string already contains `@@@`?

Comment: That is why I mentioned, its a workaround and use special combination which is not expected in the string.